# How find this $\int_{0}^{\infty}xe^{-x}\left(\int_{0}^{\pi/2}(1-e^{x-x\csc{t}})\sec^2{\!t}\,\mathrm dt\right)^2\,\mathrm dx=\frac{1}{3}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

This problem was taken from [here](http://integralsandseries.prophpbb.com/topic61.html):

> Show that $$\int_{0}^{\infty}xe^{-x}\left(\int_{0}^{\pi/2}(1-e^{x-x\csc{t}})\sec^2{\!t}\,\mathrm dt\right)^2\,\mathrm dx=\dfrac{1}{3}$$

my idea:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}xe^{-x}\left(\int_{0}^{\pi/2}(1-e^{x-x\csc{t}})\sec^2{\!t}\,\mathrm dt\right)^2\,\mathrm dx=\dfrac{1}{3}=\int_{0}^{\infty}x^3e^xK^2_{0}(x)\,\mathrm dx?$$

where $K_{0}(x)$ is the [Bessel function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function).

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to make it take up less vertical space -- this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions. See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9730) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future questions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: A possible situation is that a typo has made in the original post, and the integral should be $\int_{0}^{\infty}xe^{-\color{red}{2}x}\left(\int_{0}^{\pi/2}(1-e^{x-x\csc{t}})\sec^2{\!t}\,\mathrm dt\right)^2\,\mathrm dx$. This indeed evaluates to $\frac13$.

Answer (score 1):

The answer $\frac 1 3 $ seems not to be true. Mathematica 9.0.1.0 calculates both the inner integral (which indeed equals $x \exp (x) K_0(x)$) and the integral under consideration in a   closed form.
The result is expressed in terms of the EllipticE, EllipticK, and hypergeometric functions.
Its numerical value equals  2.85645. The same numerical result is produced by Maple. The Mathematica *.nb file exported as a *.pdf file can be downloaded from [RapidShare](http://rapidshare.com/files/3456931557/HardIntegrate.pdf).